# JetPack Compose Changes Two Unrelated Variables on View Model Event

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm facing a strange behavior with Jetpack Compose as following,

Models :

```
data class Brand(
    var name: String = "",
    var models : List<Model> = listOf()
)
data class Model(
    var name: String = ""
)
data class Car(
    var brand : Brand = Brand()
)
```

View Model :

```
class AppViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var brandsList : MutableList<Brand> = mutableListOf()
    private val car  = Car()
    init {
        brandsList.addAll(generateBrandData())
    }

    fun onEvent(event : UIEvent){
        when(event){
            is UIEvent.BrandSelected -> {
                car.brand = event.brand
                println(brandsList)
                println(car)
            }
            is UIEvent.ModelSelected -> {
                car.brand.models = listOf(event.model)
                println(brandsList)
                println(car)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun generateBrandData() : List<Brand>{
        return listOf(Brand("brand A", listOf(Model("model AA"), Model("model AB"), Model("model AC"))),
            Brand("brand B", listOf(Model("model AB"), Model("model BB"), Model("model BC"))))
    }
}
```

Screen :

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val vm = remember {
    AppViewModel()
    }
    val selectedBrand = remember {
        mutableStateOf(Brand())
    }
    
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(vertical = 20.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {

        LazyRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            items(vm.brandsList) { brand ->
                OutlinedButton(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedBrand.value = brand
                        vm.onEvent(UIEvent.BrandSelected(brand))
                    },
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = brand.name,
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                    )
                }

            }
        }

        LazyRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            items(selectedBrand.value.models) { model ->
                OutlinedButton(
                    onClick = {
                        vm.onEvent(UIEvent.ModelSelected(model))
                    },
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = model.name,
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                    )
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to show the list of brands and models for user and assign the chosen values to the view model `Car Object` using the `UIEvent`, the issue is that after the user clicks on any model row, I noticed that this event will not only effects the `Car Object` its also changes the `brandsList` as well!? as obvious the `brandsList` has 3 models in each brand but when the user choose any model and trigger the `ModelSelected Event` I noticed that the `brandList` will also be changed and the selected brand within will only have 1 model!! (the user selection).

Im really confused why is that happening!, any help, ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find the issue in this below piece of code that you assign by reference the brand of car with selected brand not by value so when you assign models of brand of the car model it affects the main brandslist

```
        is UIEvent.BrandSelected -> {
            car.brand = event.brand
            println(brandsList)
            println(car)
        }
```

Solution:
use copy of object instead of assign by reference

```
        is UIEvent.BrandSelected -> {
            car.brand = event.brand.copy()
            println(brandsList)
            println(car)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but please could you check and explain again cause i'm setting the `car object ` brand models on the event not the `brandsList` or the `selectedBrand`, I'm not changing the `brandsList` which is my main issue, check the view model (the `car object` and the `brandsList` are unrelated)

Comment: hello @MohammedRiyadh thanks for your clarification please check answer now as you were using assignment **by reference** instead of assignment by **by value** that's why it reflected in car model and also in brands list

Comment: Thanks man, my bad i missed this point